# Multistep form .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working in .net MVC3. I have a multi step form

1. step1: fillin username, password, confirm password
2. step2: fill in additional info

problem:
once user fills in step1 he/she should not be able to go back. however there is always a case where user clicks browser 'back' button. in that case all the info (except password) is pre-filled. I want to aler user (in step2) when back button is clicked that none of the info in step 1 will be updated OR somehow disable back button. is that possible? what are some valid solutions?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Darin said, you cannot disable the back button.

However, what you can do is make the multi step form submit each step via ajax.  That way, a back button will not take them to the previous step in the form, but to the page they were on before they started the form.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the back button. You could try cheating by putting the following script in the view of step 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.go(1);
</script>
```